# python flask-user www domain has different session

Tags: python, session, gevent, flask-login

I have a website use flask-user and gevent and I found a problem with the sessions

if I logged in using www.example.com
then enter the same website without www like example.com I will find my self not logged in!

I should have the session for www.example.com works on example.com because they are the same
and I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: That's more of an issue of how your server is setup. I assume you'd want the non-www site to redirect you to the www site, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue is related on how session and cookies work.
Usually, when you login on a website, it stores a cookie with the exact domain you entered, therefore if you logged in on `www.example.com` the cookie will be set to the same domain - which is not accessible from `example.com`.

If you would like the cookie / session to be detected from all the domains, you should set the cookie as `.example.com` or if working with modern browsers only, you might set it as `example.com` - and it will be accessible from all subdomains.

You may read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain).